# PySpark: java.io.EOFException

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-hadoop, pyspark, error-handling

System:

- 1 name node, 4 cores, 16 GB RAM
- 1 master node, 4 cores, 16 GB RAM
- 6 data nodes, 4 cores, 16 GB RAM each
- 6 worker nodes, 4 cores, 16 GB RAM each
- around 5 Terabytes of storage space

The data nodes and worker nodes exist on the same 6 machines and the name node and master node exist on the same machine. In our docker compose, we have `6 GB` set for the master, `8 GB` set for name node, `6 GB` set for the workers, and `8 GB` set for the data nodes.

---

> I have 2 `rdds` which I am calculating the cartesian product of, applying a function I wrote to it, and then storing the data in Hadoop as parquet tables. After around 180k parquet tables written to Hadoop, the python worker unexpectedly crashes due to EOFException in Java.

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(
"TBG Input Creation App").setMaster("spark://master:7077").setAll(
[('spark.executor.memory', '6g'), 
 ('spark.driver.memory', '4g'),
 ('spark.executor.heartbeatInterval', '3s'),
 ('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', '-XX:+UseG1GC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps'),
 ('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions', '-XX:+UseG1GC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps')])

rdd_cart = rdd.cartesian(rdd2)
rdd.unpersist()
rdd2.unpersist()

rdd_cart.foreach(lambda row: calc_model(row, fields, vfp_fields))
```

Then inside the `calc_model` function, I write out the parquet table. After the crash, I can re-start the run with PySpark filtering out the ones I all ready ran but after a few thousand more, it will crash again with the same EOFException. I am using `foreach` since I don't care about any returned values and simply just want the tables written to Hadoop.

> How can identify the root cause of this Py4JJavaError and fix it to prevent constant crashing of the workers?

[stackoverflow relevant question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086923/pyspark-throws-java-io-eofexception-when-reading-big-files-with-boto3)

---

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 10 in stage 148.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 10.3 in stage 148.0 (TID 4253, 10.0.5.19, executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:322)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:443)
 at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:421)
 at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
 at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
 at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
 at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
 at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
 at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:939)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:428)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1602)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
 at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1823)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1772)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1761)
 at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
 at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:322)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:443)
 at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:421)
 at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
 at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
 at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
 at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
 at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
 at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:939)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:428)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look at memory use:

Spark is (I presume) using all 4 cores, each with 6GB RAM (`('spark.executor.memory', '6g')`); plus 4GB for the driver (`'spark.driver.memory', '4g'`); the spark result size limit defaults to 1GB (but I don't think you've got as far as a result yet); and maybe a bit for the OS.

That's maybe 26 to 30GB getting used vs node memory of 16 GB.

So, your choice seems to be:

- dial down the RAM settings on spark
- add more RAM (easy if in the cloud, but that isn't clear here)
- sample the data

Comment: I have tried decreasing memory limits but all the same results.

Comment: If the total memory being made available is now below the system memory, then maybe sample the data to something small enough that it really ought to work is worth a go?

Comment: Alternatively, it isn't clear what `calc_model` is doing or the size of the data it is getting. Is there something there that is breaking on this size of data? Would an alternative to `forEach`, e.g. a `map` or `foreachPartition` avoid some repeated action there that is being costly?

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error,but not the RDD Memory calibration, the problem was infact with the installation , had been upgrading part of the libraries , there was no proper handshake for some internal libraries which was pushing the Python EOF error even after tweaking the memory.

Created a Virtual environment and ran Pyspark there worked as expected. Just to make sure have ran an automated load test for 50 iterations all worked good on the same large files or similar sized files for different days.

Confirming the reason for the crash is not the file size and memory for my situation.

Hope this can be of any use to other looking for a similar error out in the web